# Disable ValidationSummary For Certain Validators

Tags: asp.net

The ValidationSummary panel shows up, even if the validator does not have an 'ErrorMessage'. When I click on Submit with invalid login, the error shows up in summary. That part's fine. When I submit with empty textboxes, it should show only the '*', but it also shows an empty summary panel. How can I prevent this. [Have a css class for .summary,header, summary ul, .summary ul li].

JS:

```
function validateTextBox(sender, args) {
        var target = document.getElementById(sender.controltovalidate);
        var is_valid = target.value != "";
        if (is_valid) {
            target.className = "";
        }
        else {
            target.className = "validate";
        }
        args.IsValid = is_valid;
    }
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vs" runat="server" CssClass="summary"   
 ValidationGroup="vsGroup" DisplayMode="BulletList" EnableClientScript="true" 
 HeaderText="<div class='header'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Please Correct The 
 Following</div>" />

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" class=""></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
 ValidationGroup="vsGroup" ControlToValidate="txtSurname"  
 ClientValidationFunction="validateTextBox" Text="*" 
 ForeColor="Red" ValidateEmptyText="true" ></asp:CustomValidator>

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtLogin" runat="server" class=""></asp:TextBox>
 //....CustomValidator2 just as above..
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
 ControlToValidate="txtLogin" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" 
 ValidationExpression="^[a-z]{8,10}$" Display="Dynamic" 
 ErrorMessage="Login Does Not Match The Requirements" ValidationGroup="vsGroup" 
 EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="vsGroup" />
```

Comment: Have few other textboxes in form with similar validations. Will provide css classes if needed. Do Not have any codebehind for page_load or submit, as I only want client side validaton.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `ShowValidationErrors` property to `false` for the `ValidationSummary` control. Set this value to 
true if the validation summary from validator controls should be displayed; otherwise, false.
BY default this value is `true`.

Read [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.showvalidationerrors.aspx).

**EDIT:**

In case you need to disable ValidationSummary for some of controls and not all, you can do this on client side as well as server side.

```
var CustomVal = document.getElementById('CustomValidator1ClientID'); 
ValidatorEnable(CustomVal, false);
```

Check this Link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8635/Custom-Validation-Summary-in-ASP-NET  and this one too: [ASP.NET Validation Summary: How to disable validator with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148763/asp-net-validation-summary-how-to-disable-validator-with-javascript)

On server side, you can do as below in your `Page_Load` to check whether any Validator has its `ErrorMessage` set and if not, then disable the Validator:

```
if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage))
 //if ErrorMessage is empty, disable this validator only
CustomValidator1.Enabled=false;
```

**IInd Case::** when you want to disable only the `ValidationSummary` and NOT the Validators
in this case you just set the `ValidationGroup` property as below :

// Markup

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vs" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group1"...
```

// Code behind

```
protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage))
         //if ErrorMessage is empty, exclude this from Validation Summary
        CustomValidator1.ValidationGroup=""; 
        CustomValidator2.ValidationGroup="Group1";
 }
```

Now make sure you DO ASSIGN a `ValidationGroup` property to your `ValidationSummary` control. **So, Idea is**: All such controls whose error message should be shown in `ValidationSummary`,  set their `ValidationGroup` property same as your `ValidationSummary`'s `ValidationGroup` property.

Those controls whose Error message should NOT be shown in `ValidationSummary`, simply set their `ValidationGroup` property to empty.

**NOTE**: you may also set the `ValidationGroup`  property for `ValidationSummary` in code behind.Also. make sure you also add the `ValidationGroup` property and `CausesValidation` property to your Submit button Markup, Something like: `<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vsGroup" CausesValidation="true"/>`

**NOTE 2** :: ***Even when there are NO errors, the `ValidationSummary`  will still be visible with the below similar kind of HTML***:

```
<div id="vs" class="validationSummary" style="">
<ul></ul>
```

*This is a default behaviour of Validation summary OR a Bug kind of thing if you want to say so*. Check this Post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1657025.aspx/2/10.

So in case you want to hide the above HTML when there is NO error, check simply if there are any `li` elements, if not , hide `ValidationSummary` errors completely.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
          if ($(".validationSummary li:visible").length === 0) {
               $(".validationSummary").hide();
          }
     });
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Ruby, Edited my answer to allow the scenario you are looking for

Comment: Please check the IInd case of my answer. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Ok. This seems fine. Please make sure you also add the ValidationGroup  property and CausesValidation property to your Submit button Markup, like: <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vsGroup" CausesValidation="true"/>

Comment: OK. Then you also need to add ErrorMessage property to TxtName's custom validator.

Comment: ValidationSummary will only show ErrorMessage value. Is the whole of your ValidationSummary going blank ??? or is it just for CustomValidator1 that NO message is shown ??

Comment: This should not be the case. Validation summary picks up message only when ErrorMessage property is specified. Check if anywhere you are setting it , specially your CSS CLASS: ValidationSummary. May be this class shows bulletlist always.

Comment: Just check once after removing this CSS class from markup of ValidationSummary.

Comment: Yes, please update atleast your new markup which you find satisfactory

Comment: @RUBY: Finally reproduced the issue I guess, which you were getting. Check my answer, See :  NOTE 2. I guess this is creating problems. The only good solution till now i know is mentioned. Let me know if you know a better solution.

Comment: Getting closer.Tried that.The summary control was in a <td> & the cssclass was assigned to the Summary control. So, changed it to:     <div id = "vsDiv" class="validationsummary">
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vs" runat="server" CssClass="" ValidationGroup="vsGroup" DisplayMode="BulletList"              EnableClientScript="true" HeaderText="<div class='validationheader'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Please Correct The Following</div>"/>. The div cant have the css right, as it would always show the colored block. Where am I going wrong!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can either set it to `Enabled="false"` or `Visible="false"` and then when the `CustomValidator` is triggered (if needed) you can in the code behind enable it as `vs.Enabled="true"` or and `vs.Visible="true"`

Comment: I do not have any CS or JS code for those other validators. How can I enable summary for them. eg:  <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDateOfBirth"
                            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date Format (Date Of Birth)" ForeColor="Red"
                            Text="*" Type="Date" MinimumValue="01-01-1000" MaximumValue="31-12-9999" ></asp:RangeValidator>